# JQuery: Get each item in RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have an `asp:RadioButtonList` that is filled dynamically:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
        <asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="radioListRepeatColumn" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:RadioButtonList>   
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Whenever the selected value changes, I want to run through each item in the list, and change the background color of a nested span (class `qcode`). The problem is that `each` only returns the whole radio button list itself (`$(this)` maps to `RadioButtonList1`).

```
$('#RadioButtonList1').change(function () {
    $('#RadioButtonList1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).children('qcode').css('background-color', '#E9E9E9');
        } else {
            $(this).children('qcode').css('background-color', '#3388cc');
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

The html generated by jQuery mobile is massive, but I will add some bits so everyone can get an idea of what is being generated:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all ui-mini">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
                <table id="RadioButtonList1" class="radioListRepeatColumn" onkeydown="return DidYouHitEnter(event);" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><span onchange="SetTextValues();"><div class="ui-radio ui-mini"><label for="RadioButtonList1_0" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-radio-off ui-first-child"><span class="qcode">1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="qcodetext">Text</span></label><input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="_ctl0:MainBodyPlaceHolder:NIGHTSTOT:RadioButtonList1" value="31:31" onclick="SetTextValues();"></div></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span onchange="SetTextValues();"><div class="ui-radio ui-mini"><label for="RadioButtonList1_1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-radio-off"><span class="qcode">2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="qcodetext">Text</span></label><input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="_ctl0:MainBodyPlaceHolder:NIGHTSTOT:RadioButtonList1" value="32:32" onclick="SetTextValues();"></div></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span onchange="SetTextValues();"><div class="ui-radio ui-mini"><label for="RadioButtonList1_2" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-radio-off"><span class="qcode">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="qcodetext">Text</span></label><input id="RadioButtonList1_2" type="radio" name="_ctl0:MainBodyPlaceHolder:NIGHTSTOT:RadioButtonList1" value="33:33" onclick="SetTextValues();"></div></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span onchange="SetTextValues();"><div class="ui-radio ui-mini"><label for="RadioButtonList1_3" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-radio-off"><span class="qcode">4</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="qcodetext">Text</span></label><input id="RadioButtonList1_3" type="radio" name="_ctl0:MainBodyPlaceHolder:NIGHTSTOT:RadioButtonList1" value="34:34" onclick="SetTextValues();"></div></span></td>
        </tbody></table>    
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**EDIT 2**

I have found a way to work around the `runat=server` issue.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        foreach (ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)   
            li.Attributes.Add("onchange","SetTextValues()");
}
```

**What I need now is a way to get every item in a RadioButtonList (`$('#RadioButtonList1').each()` line), so I can change the colors of the nested span**

Comment: Show the rendered HTML from that ASP code.

Comment: It's an ID, it's unique, why would there be more elements with the same ID ?

Comment: Added output. I did a .each, because I thought that would go through each item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The `runat="server"` attribute forces your web page to make a refresh every time an event like `onselectedindexchanged` is fired. This refresh overrides anything jQuery could do on the child elements  in the `$('#RadioButtonList1').change()` jQuery function.

Either change the color at serverSide when your serverSide event is fired or remove the runat attribute and `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` serverSide event and manage all from the $.change() jQuery function.

Comment: That's a good catch, but I can get around that, I can append the code to change each radio button color to another javascript onClick function (which add to each list item after a postback)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know if you are still having issue with it.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#RadioButtonList1 input').change(function () {
                $('#RadioButtonList1 input').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).closest("qcode").children().css('background-color', '#E9E9E9');
                    } else {
                        $(this).closest("qcode").children().css('background-color', '#3388cc');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I gave that a try with no luck. My code was a little different than yours (no .change line, since I was adding this to another onchange event), but the debugger did not hit the `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`.  When I type `$('#RadioButtonList1 input')` into the Google Chrome console, it returns `[]`